# WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate bind ItemSource to "nested" class property

Tags: c#, wpf

Let me give you a example class before I explain my problem:

```
class ExampleNodeClass
public ContainerExample Container {get; set;}
some other properties

class ContainerExample 
public ObservableCollection<ExampleNodeClass> Children {get; set;}
some other properties
```

I want to use a TreeView and use a HierarchicalDataTemplate  for the ExampleNodeClass, I know that you can usually bind the ItemSource propert to the "children" but with the example class above the "children" are not directly inside the ExampleNodeClass, but they are "nested" inside the Container property of the ExampleNodeClass.

Is there any good solution how the HierarchicalDataTemplate  could still work in this example and bind the ItemSource to the "nested" Children property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda missed the most obvious solution, I can just change my binding to access the "nested" property by changing the binding path of the ItemSource to Container.Children.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any good solution how the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` could still work in this example and bind the `ItemSource` to the "nested" `Children` property?

No, there isn't.

That's why you should bind to *view* models, i.e. whenever your current type doesn't fit the MVVM binding model for one reason or another, you should transform it into (create) another type that does.

In this case, the transformation should be straight-forward:

```
treeView.ItemsSource = exampleNodes.SelectedMany(x => x.Container).ToArray();
```

`ExampleNodeClass` is not hierarchical and therefore not a candidate view model. `ContainerExample` is.